# CDAP API Calling in GCP failing

Tags: rest, curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am trying to create a sample Pipeline in my Data Fusion instance, as part of my Project POC.
I am using CDAP API for automate the pipeline creation.
I am facing issue while calling below CDAP API in GCP,

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -w"\n" -X PUT "[My-GCP-Data-Fusion-Endpoint]/v3/namespaces/default/apps/MyPipeline" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @/home/saji_s/config.jason

The content in config.jason is,

{
  "name": "MyPipeline",
  "artifact": {
    "name": "cdap-data-pipeline",
    "version": "6.0.0",
    "scope": "system"
  },
  "config": {
    . . .
    "connections": [ . . . ],
    "engine": "mapreduce",
    "postActions": [ . . . ],
    "stages": [ . . . ],
    "schedule": "0 * * * *",
  },
  "**ui**": {
    . . .
  }
}

I am getting Error Like, " Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1 "

Could you please help me here, I just want to create a sample Pipeline in my Data Fusion instance, as part of my Project POC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resolved, the issues was with the jason file and after preparing the correct jason file the scipt executed and the pipeline deployed successfully